# Db Mirror Issue

Tags: sql-server, mirroring, cluster

We are having a Weird issue with the DB Mirroring and to post the the issue I will have to explain our Architecture first.

We have a TWO Nodes [NODE 1 and NODE 2] cluster with Two FCIs Installed on it [SQLPRD01 and SQLPRDO2] and this is a active/active cluster i.e SQLPRD01 preferred owner is NODE 1 and the preferred Owner for SQLPRD02 is NODE2. From these clustered Instances we are mirroring the DBs to a different cluster in a different Data center for DR purposes which has Two Nodes [NODE 3 and NODE 4] and they have SQLDR01 and SQLDR02 Installed on them with NODE 3 as Preferred Owner for SQLDR01 and NODE 4 as Preferred Owner for SQLDR02. So the DB Mirroing is established from [SQLPRD01 to SQLDR01] and [SQLPRD02 to SQLDR02] respectively.
Last Week we ran into an issue on SQLPRD02 where the app is getting time out and the Mirroring is going to disconnected state but when I fail over the SQLPRD02 from NODE 2 to NODE 1, the mirroring resumes and the app is able to connect without any issues. It was Intermittent last week but since yesterday the issue is consistent i.e. the Mirroring will be in disconnected state when I fail over the SQL to its Preferred node [Node 2] but works fine on NODE 1.

So far I troubleshooted below items,

1) ODBC/UDL/Telnet was succesfull from all PRD to DR nodes and vice versa. Also same tests are done from App Servers which were successfull. 
2) These are phyical machines so we replaced the N/W cables on PRD Cluster.
3) Verified the permissions for SQL Service Accounts [which is used in mirror setup]on both SQLPRD02 and SQLDR02, it has SA access and connect to endpoints access.
4) All the patch/hotfixes/firmware updates are at the same level and the SQL version is 2102 which is at the same level on both PRD and DR.
5) Raised a case with MS and they ran PSSDiag and so far they have not found the smoking gun.

Exact Error Message on SQLPRD02 Instance:

Message
Database mirroring connection error 4 'The connection was closed by the remote end, or an error occurred while receiving data: '64(The specified network name is no longer available.)'' for 'TCP://SQL Cluster/Network Name for SQLDR02,port'.